# Is there a simple way to organize upload files with date?

Tags: files, wysiwyg

I am using CKEditor with CKFinder. I know how to change the upload path. But the setting only have "%u"(UID) and "$n"(UserName) token for the upload path. I want to organize the files by date. How can I achieve?

Sorry for my English. Thanks for reading this question.

Comment: Check first Related question. [Organizing uploaded files in folders created by date](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2375/organizing-uploaded-files-in-folders-created-by-date)

Comment: @enzipher Thanks your reply. But I have read this question before and I want to organize by CKFinder not Drupal field. I have Google for a long time. Many info are not relate with Drupal, not useful.